# getting a new eclipse and complete removal of previous versions that maven can work

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

[image]Currently I have eclipse indigo in my system and it is not working correctly like when i try to open market place it displays an error.I have java 7 on my system. Maven is not working as it is unable to connect. What I want to do now is completely remove this eclipse and get a fresh eclipse so that maven and all this things work fine. Removing and downloading a new copy didn't solve this problem as i have done it three times. I guess i  need to remove few more files. please suggest how should i do it.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of an error?

Comment: added..........

Comment: If you do not have something particular you want to save you can try to remove the .eclipse folder. This one is normally located in you \Users or /home directory (under your home folder). This normally solves most problems with plugins. If you want to save some settings, you have to find the settings files and copy them to a safe location first.